# Can a D3 line/area chart work on unordered data?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Please refer the following link : 
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Here the data is ordered (in sequence) like jan 2000, feb 2000 etc but i want to make this d3 graph work on unordered data like jan 2001 ,feb 2000 etc. Is it possible ?

Comment: try something first, when you encounter problems, ask your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

The line generator or the area generator (which is the one in that blocks) will generate a line (or an area) based on the input data *in its order*. The API makes it clear:

> `d3.line()`: Generates a line for the given array of data. Depending on this line generator’s associated curve, the given input data **may need to be sorted** by x-value before being passed to the line generator. (emphasis mine)

Let's see this in a basic example. I have an array of values and years, in which the years are not sorted:

```
var data = [{
  year: 2010,
  value: 100
}, {
  year: 2017,
  value: 70
}, {
  year: 2012,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2016,
  value: 10
}, {
  year: 2013,
  value: 90
}, {
  year: 2014,
  value: 20
}, {
  year: 2011,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2015,
  value: 40
}];
```

This is the line chart we have if I pass the data to the line generator the way it is right now:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [{
  year: 2010,
  value: 100
}, {
  year: 2017,
  value: 70
}, {
  year: 2012,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2016,
  value: 10
}, {
  year: 2013,
  value: 90
}, {
  year: 2014,
  value: 20
}, {
  year: 2011,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2015,
  value: 40
}];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseTime(d.year)
});

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.year
  }))
  .range([0, 300]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  }))
  .range([150, 0]);

var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.year)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value)
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "teal")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now the same code, but sorting the data:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return d3.ascending(a.year, b.year)
});
```

Here is the result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [{
  year: 2010,
  value: 100
}, {
  year: 2017,
  value: 70
}, {
  year: 2012,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2011,
  value: 10
}, {
  year: 2013,
  value: 90
}, {
  year: 2014,
  value: 20
}, {
  year: 2016,
  value: 50
}, {
  year: 2015,
  value: 40
}];

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseTime(d.year)
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return d3.ascending(a.year, b.year)
})

var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.year
  }))
  .range([0, 300]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  }))
  .range([150, 0]);

var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.year)
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value)
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)

svg.append("path")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "teal")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("d", lineGenerator(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```